# Query to calculate "trailing twelve-month sum(column)" for 100s of dates in one query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table:

**Dividends History Table**

```
id | date | dividends_received_value
 1 | 2020-01-02 | 0.00
 2 | 2020-01-03 | 1.30
 3 | 2020-01-04 | 0.45
...
```

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to get:

- One row for each date
- Each row contains the

sum(dividends_received_value) for the past year of data **relative to the date in that row** ("trailing twelve months")

Can this be done purely in SQL?

Is there any way to perform this calculation within a reasonable amount of time, if I have like 3000 dates/rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function:

```
select t.*,
       sum(dividends_received_value) over (order by date
                                           range between interval 1 year preceding and current row
                                          ) as trailing_12_month
from t;
```

If you can have multiple rows per date, then put this logic in an aggregation query:

```
select t.date, sum(dividends_received_value) as on_day,
       sum(sum(dividends_received_value)) over (order by date
                                                range between interval 1 year preceding and current row
                                               ) as trailing_12_month
from t
group by t.date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a538ba01dd3de7e626da748366b70b45) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help -- I'm getting a syntax error from the first query (in MySQL) that I'm having trouble fixing. I tried putting a `(` before `sum` but that did not fix it. Would you mind taking another look?

Comment: @HC_ . . . This does require MySQL 8+

Comment: I noticed that and updated to `Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.0.2` just now -- still no luck unfortunately. Using query: `select (sum(dividends_received_value) over (order by date range between interval 1 year preceding and current row)) as trailing_12_month from myTable;` but getting `check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'interval 1 year preceding and current row)`. Does that Syntax look proper to you? I'll double-check MySQL version.

Comment: I got this simplified query to work: `select (sum(dividends_received_value) over ()) as trailing_12_month from myTable`. It looks like the syntax inside of `over()` is where I am struggling.

Comment: Hmmm . . . It seems that MySQL supports something that MariaDB doesn't:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=a538ba01dd3de7e626da748366b70b45.

Comment: Just noticed that too -- thank you! I'm going to try to see if I can switch from MariaDB to MySQL... didn't even realize there was a difference/I wasn't using official MySQL

Comment: If you have a row for each date, then `rows between 364 preceding and current row` should work -- and is probably close enough for what you want to do.

Comment: Solved by switching from `MariaDB` to `MySQL 8.0.23` and using this query: `select *, (sum(dividends_received_value) over (order by date range between interval 1 year preceding and current row)) as ttm from myTable`. Massive thank you for your help